# 2 Dimensional Array, ASCII Art in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ascii-art

My code is supposed to take 3 numbers the user chooses, and then a size also inputted my user to output a 2D array of ASCII art. I keep getting a syntax error for line 30, my first "else if" statement. The prompt box also does not pop up.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> ASCII Art Generator </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="Header"> ASCII Art </h1>
  <p id= "Create"> </p>
  <script>
  var userChoice = [];

  for (var i=0; i < 3; i++){
    userChoice[i]=prompt("Enter any character");
  }
  console.log(userChoice);

  var myArt = "";
  var size=prompt("Enter any number");

  do {
    prompt("Enter any number");
  }
  while(!Number(size));
  console.log(size);

  for (var x=0; x<size; x++){
    for (var y=0; y<size; y++){
      if ((x+y)/6 != 0){
        myArt += userChoice[0];
      }
      else if {
        myArt += userChoice[1];
      }
      else if {
        myArt += userChoice[2];
      }
    }
    myArt += "<BR>";
  }


  document.getElementById("Create").innerHTML = myArt;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `else if {` Your else if doesn't have a condition. It should be `else if (some_condition) {`.

Comment: Wow -_- should the math be the same for the condition, I'm confused on how to think about how this if I dont know what size the user will input. Thanks for you help

Comment: @Vivek Nevermind solved that question on my own, now the problem I'm running into is the prompt asks me to input size twice, is there something wrong with my do while loop.

Comment: Yes, your do while loop has a serious issue. If the value of `size` is 1 or more then the loop body will be run once (only once whatever `size` be). And if `size` is zero then your do while loop will become an infinite loop.

Comment: `prompt asks me to input size twice` - You have written the code for that.
`var size=prompt("Enter any number"); //First prompt`
And the second prompt is inside the do while loop.